# Redirect Wordpress URL of subpage is missing

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I'm struggling to come up with a regex that would achieve the following.
I have a custom post type called `/blog/` and I would like to redirect based off of the following conditions:

`/blog/sample-category/post-title` -> 200, page resolves NO redirection.

`/blog/sample-category/` -> 301, redirect to `/topics/sample-category/` (if the post title is left out of the URL, redirect the page to the category archive.

Every redirect I try `^/blog/(.*)` etc... fails to allow `/blog/sample-category/post-title` to resolve...

Looking for a friend here!

Comment: can you provide some redirects you tried in your question by editing it?

Comment: Well, agnostic of redirects — I want `/blog/sample-category/post-title` to work, and anything that is without the last string of the url eg `/blog/sample-category/` to redirect to a different page.

Comment: it's clear. I mean to provide some code you tried

Comment: Ah, `^/blog/(.*)` --- `^/blog/(.*)/(.*)` --- `!/blog/(.*)/(.*)`